# How to update mongodb document with only checked checkbox data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

If I have data that looks like this:

```
    _id:60e2edf7014df85fd8b6e073
    routineName:"test"
    username: "tester"
    monday:[{
        _id: 60e430d45395d73bf41c7be8
        exercise: "a"
    }{
        _id: 60e4329592e3fa445836d983
        exercise: "b"
}]
tuesday:[{
    _id:60e2ee8962c0c15840ecc69b
    exercise: "c"
}]
```

What would be the best way to push data from a checkbox form? This is what I have so far:

```
router.post('/routines/:username/:day', async (req, res) =>{ //add exercise from add page
    let day = req.params.day
    try{
    await Routine.updateOne( {routineUsername: req.user.username}, { $push: { [day]: {$each: [
        {exercise: req.body.a}, {exercise: req.body.b}, {exercise: req.body.c}, {exercise: req.body.d}, 
    ]} } } )
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Exercise added to routine!')
    res.redirect('/')
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }   
})
```

And this will update the document but if you only check one checkbox, the other one will be stored as an empty object. What's the solution to this?

Comment: Create a `updatePayload` before running `updateOne`. Add checks to see what elements are checked push them to your updatePayload only.

Comment: Should I do that by iterating through my req.body and pushing it into updatePayload if it exists?

Comment: Do you have dynamic number of checkboxes? Or you only have specific ones like a, b, c, d

Comment: Only specific ones yes

Comment: Storing empty object is not a good idea for your handling. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have specific checkboxes. What you can do is create an update payload first by checking if a checkbox is applied and only push that one in array.

```
// destruct day
const { day } = req.params;

// create an empty payload
const updatePayload = { [day]: [] };

// now check your specific checkboxes 
if (req.body.a) {
   updatePayload[day].push({ exercise: req.body.a });
}

// and so on

// now finally update
await Routine.updateOne( {routineUsername: req.user.username}, updatePayload);
```

Now, one thing here is that, I replace the current array with new ones so the previous check boxes that were ticked are removed and automatically not checked. So every time you'll have to push all the ticked boxes.

A better way to handle checkboxes would be to change your current strategy and push an array of checkboxes from your frontend for a specific day. Store all your checkboxes in db and maintain a key like `isChecked` to check if checkbox is ticked or not. Then you can replace the array completely.

Something like this:

```
// destruct day and checkboxes
const { day, checkboxes } = req.params;

// and simply push
await Routine.updateOne( {routineUsername: req.user.username}, 
        { [day]: checkboxes });
```

Again there could be numerous other ways to achieve this as well.